# Error Call to a member function with() on string Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

A la hora de ejecutar la siguiente función destroy, me aparece un error con respecto a la función with de laravel, me podrían ayudar.

```
function destroy($id,$route='none' ){
    $destroy = User::find($id);
    $destroy->delete();
    if($route == 'equal'){
        return back()->with('info','Usuario eliminado');
    }else{
        return route('home')->with('info','Usuario eliminado');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenes que hacer uso del metodo `redirect()` antes del `back()` o del `route()`

```
function destroy($id,$route='none' ){
    $destroy = User::find($id);
    $destroy->delete();
    if($route == 'equal'){
        return redirect()->back()->with('info','Usuario eliminado');
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('info','Usuario eliminado');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te marca ese error por que primero debes acceder al método **redirect** luego a **route** y al final al método **with** y lo mismo para el método **back**

```
return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'Usuario eliminado');
```

Aquí tienes mas información al respecto

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-named-routes